# How to call a function from another class, where the function uses local variable

Tags: c++, boost-graph, max-flow

I have two classes `MaxFlow` and `MinMaxFlow`.

`MaxFlow` uses boost graph to create a graph from a network topology:

```cpp
class MaxFlow {
 public:
  MaxFlow : g_() { createGraph(); } //constructor
  void createGraph();
  void modifyGraph(); // modify the graph to use boost maxflow algorithm
  int maxFlowAlgo(); // use g_ and some other util local variables
 private:
  Graph g_;
  ...   // some other helper containers created during createGraph()
}
```

`MaxFlow` maintains a local variable `g_` since we only need one instance to do all the work here.
`MinMaxFlow` iterates every edge in the graph to find a minimum max flow if we fail that `edge` (set capacity to 0):

```cpp
class MinMaxFlow {
 public:
  int getMinMaxFlow() {
    int minMaxFlow = INT_MAX;
    MaxFlow maxFlowObj; // create a new obj
    maxFlowObj.modifyGraph(); // I suppose this modify current obj
    for (auto edge : graph_edges) {
      // maxFlowAlgo will return incorrect value after several runs
      int maxFlowVal = maxFlowObj.maxFlowAlgo();
      int minMaxFlow = std::min(minMaxFlow, maxFlowVal);
    }
    return minMaxFlow;
  }
}
```

Now the problem is, `maxFlowAlgo` is based on local variable `g_` in class `MaxFlow`, when I create new object `maxFlowObj` in `MinMaxFlow`, calling `maxFlowObj.maxFlowAlgo()` will use its own data, which makes the result unpredictable. 
So my question is: how can I use the method(like `maxFlowAlgo`) belongs to `MaxFlow` in the second class `MinMaxFlow` if the method uses local variables in `MaxFlow`?

Update: I have figured out the problem is from `boost::boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow`, I use bundle properties and pass capacity property map into it, but this algorithm will not only modify the capacity property map, but also my original edge capacity variable! Now the workaround is that I have to store the capacity values before running the algorithm and restore them after it. It's not supposed to modify the original members, right?

Comment: `g_` is not a local variable, but a *member* variable. There is a difference.

Comment: you can make your `g_` variable static so all instances of your class "share" it. this may help: [Static Members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx#Anchor_0)

Comment: Understand what is local variable, class member and static class member. Making `g_` simply `static` will not instantly make your code correct. Why will `maxFlowAlgo` "return incorrect value after several runs"? I suppose it should be `const`. You don't use `edge` variable inside your loop. Maybe, this edge is intended to be deleted in the beginning of iteration and added in the end?

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov Thanks. I was thinking delete the edge but it may make boost graph unstable. So I use a workaround by setting the edge capacity to 0. I find the problem happens right after I call the boost max flow algorithm. I use  boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow and  bundle properties for capacity_property_map. It will modify some edge capacities. I don't see any reason for that. The algorithm shouldn't modify any graph elements, right?

Comment: @EmersonXu I'll leave answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's OK that edge capacities are changed.

Sometimes algorithms don't modify input data. On other hand, it's better to alter existing data to save resources (memory) and because altered data can make sense. After max flow algorithm is executed, edge capacities are residual capacities; in other words, how much capacity is left in each edge when graph is saturated by flow. At least one of edge will have zero residual capacity; when after second algorithm execution, it will return zero because graph is saturated.

If you want to run max flow algorithm several times, you have to preserve initial graph and copy it each time you run algorithm. Each time in the beginning of loop iteration you have to reconstruct your graph or copy it from preserved.

Since you run algorithm several times, you probably want to run it on different graphs. You probably want to copy graph and set edge capacity to zero.

Comment: Yes. I have solved the problem by constructing a default base graph. Modify it, run maxflow algorithm, restore it, and repeat these three steps for each edge groups. It runs perfect now. Thanks again for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you asked a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

IF you want to `maintains a local variable g_ since we only need one instance`, you should use [Singleton Design Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton/cpp/1), other than creating instance when you need it.